# I have a json string return by my c# function.and now I have to used it in my angular js code. then which tag I have to used

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

```
string a = ICH.GET_Status1();
```

This function return me string and I have to display this string in my angular js code

```
<body ng-controller="controllerng">    
<p>{{varName}}</p>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('appng', []);
    app.controller('controllerng', function ($scope, $http) {


                $scope.varName = a;//here i used string 



    });
</script>
```

Comment: is string a = ICH.GET_Status1(); in your mvc action method?

Comment: How do you access the c# function? REST? Please add some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the variable as a javascript global variable in your c# view.

For instance in C# MVC we can put it inside index.cshtml

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    var a = '@viewBag.a';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and then in your controller

```
.controller("MyController", function($scope){
    $scope.a = a;
});
```